# How can I install and run Docker on Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently installed Ubuntu terminal 10 on Windows 10, but I'm having issues installing Docker on Ubuntu terminal using [this Digital Ocean tutorial for Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04).

I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. 
Is the docker daemon running?
```

How can I run Docker in WSL?

Comment: Please edit with logs or errors codes.

Comment: Two things: 
1. WSL is not the same as Ubuntu in many ways.
2. You probably need to open up port 2375 as described at https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly

Comment: Should should be able to run the Docker client on WSL. Docker Engine probably not.